# Intercept browserAction.onClicked to prevent display of extension page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When the browserAction icon is clicked for my Chrome extension, I want to prevent it from showing the browserAction popup. I'm trying to use the browserAction icon to trigger the loading of a content script instead.

How would I do this?

The following doesn't prevent it from opening:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  alert('browserAction clicked');

  return false;
});
```

Here is my manifest.json entry for this:

```
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "images/icon-19.png",
      "38": "images/icon-38.png"
    },
    "default_title": "My extension"
  }
```

The docs say `This event will not fire if the browser action has a popup`, however, as you can see I don't have  a popup defined but it still doesn't work.

Comment: If you don't have a popup set, what do you mean by "browserAction HTML template window"?

Comment: @Xan I meant the popup. Sorry, mucked up the terminology. Fixed in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press [the extension button](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction), the following happens.

1. If you have a popup defined for the current tab (e.g. by the `default_popup` key in the manifest or `chrome.browserAction.setPopup`), it is shown. The `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` is **not raised**.
2. If the popup is not set (or set as empty) for the current tab, `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` is dispatched.

So, to disable this permanently, you just need to remove `default_popup` from the manifest. To disable it programmatically, you need to unset it:

```
chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
  popup: "",
  // tabId: id // optional, restrict to a single tab
});
```

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks for letting me know how to disable programmatically. Still didn't work, but then I deleted the extension entry and loaded the unpacked extension again and now it does. Appreciate the alternate route to this!

Comment: "Reload" link should do fine.